# Typescript Promise resolve syntax with narrowing type

Tags: typescript, promise

I'm trying to understand how the syntax in the following class is valid in TypeScript:

```
class Deferred<T> {
  promise: Promise<T>;
  resolve!: (value: T) => void;
  reject!: (reason?: any) => void;

  constructor() {
    this.promise = new Promise<T>((resolve, reject) => {
      this.resolve = resolve;
      this.reject = reject;
    });
  }
}
```

Specifically, how the `resolve` parameter is assignable to `this.resolve`.... Since the signature of the Promise constructor is:

`new <T>(executor: (resolve: (value: T | PromiseLike<T>) => void, reject: (reason?: any) => void) => void) => Promise<T>`

but the `resolve` field on the class is only `(value: T) => void`. Since the constructor defines that with a union type of also including `PromiseLike<T>` it would seem that this assignment shouldn't be allowed but it seems to compile + work fine. Any explanation for why this is?

Comment: [Functions are contravariant](https://dmitripavlutin.com/typescript-covariance-contravariance/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Contravariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) of functions is hard to get your head around.

Assume these two types (named after where they appear in your code);

```
type ResolveValue = (value: T | PromiseLike<T>) => void
type ResolveField = (value: T) => void
```

Now, you're wondering why

```
const value : ResolveValue = ...;
const field : ResolveField = value; // Why no compiler error?
```

is legal. Here's why:

When the compiler says

> Give me a function that I can call with a `T`

and you say

> Can I give you a function that you can call with a `T` *or* a `PromiseLike<T>`?

then the compiler says

> Sure, that's fine. I'll just never call it with the latter.

and happily assigns your `value` to `field`, because it can.

Comment: I don't think this is correct since nowhere do you assert to the compiler that `PromiseLike<T>` is not given in the code. It doesn't even matter if it's `PromiseLike<T>` or not - it can be `Set<T>` as well and it'd still work.

Comment: @caTS Surely the type of `Deferred<T>['resolve']` - `(value: T) => void;` - does assert that it's only called with `T` and not with `PromiseLike<T>`?

Comment: Oh. It seems that I've been mixing things up here and you are both correct.

Comment: But how does the compiler know that will never be called with the latter PromiseLike<T> type? Wouldn't that need to be some sort of runtime check?

Comment: @chinabuffet It knows that because (at least as a value of `field`), it's typed as `(value: T) => void`, which you're not allowed to call with a promise. So if someone call `field(new Promise(...))` that would be a compiler error.

Comment: Btw it wouldn't actually be a problem, because your function happily takes a promise. It's just that when it has a compile-time type of `(value: T) => void`, it won't get one.

Comment: Sorry but I'm still confused :( ... Since I'm supplying the executor function which accepts the resolve + reject arguments, how can it determine/know that even though there is a union type possibility based on the Promise constructor's signature that it would never be called with one? I think a big part of my confusion is why the Promise executor even defines a union type on the parameter for the resolve function.

Comment: It doesn't know that. It just knows that your function happily takes a `T`, and that's all it needs to ensure in order to allow you to assign it to the field. The fact that it would *also* accept a promise doesn't matter.

Comment: For your other question, the reason for the union type is that you can also call `resolve` with yet another promise, in which case _your_ promise would resolve to whatever that other promise resolves to.

Answer (score 0):

The signature `(value: T) => void` is a valid target for `(value: T | PromiseLike<T>)`, as it matches the wider signature (they overlap). The other way around would not work.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I'm still not understanding how they match. The left side ( `value: T` ) is the resolved promise value, but the right side seems to still be a Promise wrapper, so how do they overlap?